# AOSP not booting after OTA update (LoadImageAndAuth Failed)

Tags: android, android-source, ota

I'm trying to update my custom AOSP ROM using OTA Full update. Despite I see no errors when sideloading (adb sideload ota.zip) or installing using UpdateEngine the OTA package, bootloader fails to load the updated ROM.

```
LoadImageAndAuth Failed: Load Error
```

*RecoverySystem.verifyPackage()* finds no errors.

To build OTA packages I use the following cmds:

```
lunch aosp_walleye-userdebug
make dist DIST_DIR=dist_output
```

It is odd that the compiled OTA package is named aosp_walleye-ota-eng.andrey.zip. ENG instead of userdebug.

The ROM itself can be installed and loaded by the device with no problems.

If I compile eng build, OTA works well (bootloader boots it with no errors).

```
lunch aosp_walleye-eng
make dist DIST_DIR=dist_output
```

Are there any ways to debug the error?

My device is Pixel2.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with slots. Slot A had my custom ROM. Slot B did not.

It seems that both slots had to be flashed beforehand with the custom ROM to be able to boot full OTA update.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. Have you ever resolved the "eng" instead of "userdebug" naming thing?